# c++ opencv randu function throws 'Integer division by zero'

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, random

I'm trying to fill a `cv::Mat` with random numbers.

```
cv::Mat mat(100, 100, CV_8UC4);
cv::randu(mat, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(256));
```

The above code works fine, as long as I keep the scalars exactly as they are. Changing `0` and `256` to any other values will cause an `Integer division by zero` exception on the call to `randu`. Can anyone explain to me why? I'm using opencv3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a [bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12392) in opencv<3.4.

please update to the latest opencv (you can still stay with opencv3)